# Cant execute same script in different folder

Tags: python, c#

I have a pretty simple script running, it works in one folder but doesnt work in the other. Have been going at this for a couple hours ):. Permissions for both files are the same, script is the same, nothing python side. Seems very technical. I have tried allowing full control to the files I am attempting to interact with and the duplicated python script aswell. I tested the duplicate script in C:/ and Program Files (x86) with no resolution. The script only seems to work from one folder. Nothing is different from both scripts.

**Script I am attempting to copy into a new folder and use:**

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
def parse(p):
    q = p
    return q
#per line in textbox, create element in list
zz = ((parse(sys.argv[1]).replace("'", "")).split("\n"))
zz = list(filter(("").__ne__, zz))
last_element = zz[-1:]
last_element = (last_element[0]).split("[[")
zz = zz[:-1]
zz.append(last_element[0])
last_element = last_element[1]
if last_element == "product_url.txt":
    os.chdir(r"C:\Cactus (2022)\supported_websites\XXX")
else:
    os.chdir(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Cactus (2022)\supported_websites\XXX\XXX')
a_file = open('%s' % last_element, "w")
for x in zz:
    if x == "":
        pass
    else: 
        a_file.write("%s\n" % x)
```

**Calling from C#:**

```
MessageBox.Show(richTextBox4.Text);
panel1.Visible = false;
string task_information;
task_information = richTextBox4.Text + @"[[product_url.txt";
ProcessStartInfo rtInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C://Program Files (x86)//Cactus (2022)//repo//python.exe");
rtInfo.FileName = "C://Program Files (x86)//Cactus (2022)//repo//python.exe";
rtInfo.Arguments = "C://Cactus (2022)//modifytextfilelines.py '" + task_information + "'";
rtInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
rtInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(rtInfo);
```

**Only way it works:**

```
MessageBox.Show(richTextBox4.Text);
panel1.Visible = false;
string task_information;
task_information = richTextBox4.Text + @"[[product_url.txt";
ProcessStartInfo rtInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C://Program Files (x86)//Cactus (2022)//repo//python.exe");
rtInfo.FileName = "C://Program Files (x86)//Cactus (2022)//repo//python.exe";
rtInfo.Arguments = "C://Cogs//modifytextfilelines.py '" + task_information + "'";
rtInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
rtInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(rtInfo);
```

Let me emphasize, the script is exactly the same, copy and pasted from my "Cogs" folder. It doesnt work at all if I attempt to copy and paste it to a new folder and modify my Arguments line to that directory for C#.

**Edit:**

Did more testing, seems it is the space in "Cactus (2022)", I replaced the folder name with XXX in the pasted code below... I copy and pasted my Cogs folder into C:/ and it worked fine, I renamed it to "REPO", I changed this to "RE PO" and it stopped working. So a syntax error is the issue underneath arguments.

Comment: `os.chdir(r'C:\Program Files` --- can you try change this directory to somewhere else, such as `C:\tmp...`

Comment: Why do you write your direction separators as // in C#? Should they not be \ ?

Comment: And why are you setting the filename twice: once in the constructor for `ProcessStartInfo` and then manually against the property in the next line?

Comment: This doesnt seem to matter, may look bad haha... I am simply changing the directory underneath Arguments on a working C# block, "//" is like using "@." My script is a little messy :)

Comment: Found my folder to be set to "Read Only" under properties, hoping this fixes my issue after I manage to remove it though the folder the working script is in has the same setting, read only. It keeps reseting after I apply changes

Comment: "//" is not like using "@". "\\" is like using "@".

Comment: I copied the folder over to my C:\ drive, doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: swapped out "//" with "\" and "@", tried just "\\" aswell...